Cypress unable to find steps definition after changing the file directory
Hi can anyone help me how to fix this error message I'm getting on Cypress, Currently I'm getting an error upon changing my step_definitions file directory from
"cypress\support\step_definitions" to "cypress\support\step_definitions" Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much
I tried searching for files containing step definitions using the following search pattern templates:

cypress\e2e\features/[filepath]/**/*.{js,mjs,ts,tsx}
cypress\e2e\features/[filepath].{js,mjs,ts,tsx}
cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,mjs,ts,tsx}

These templates resolved to the following search patterns:

cypress\e2e\features/auth0/**/*.{js,mjs,ts,tsx}
cypress\e2e\features/auth0.{js,mjs,ts,tsx}
cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,mjs,ts,tsx}

These patterns matched no files containing step definitions. This almost certainly means that you have misconfigured stepDefinitions.
cucumber.json
{
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/step_definitions/**/*.ts"
  ]
}

cypress.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/features/**/*.feature",
    supportFile: "cypress/support/e2e.ts", 
    setupNodeEvents,
    baseUrl: "https://ABCBB.com.eu/", 
    env: {
      "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
        stepDefinitions: "cypress/e2e/step_definitions/**/*.ts", // Location of step definition files
      },
    },
  },
});

tsconfig.json
  "include": [
    "cypress/**/*.ts",
    "cypress/e2e/features/**/*.feature", 
    "cypress/e2e/step_definitions/**/*.ts", 
    "cypress/support/**/*.ts",
    "global.d.ts" 
  ]

settings.json
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
      "cypress/e2e/step_definitions/*.ts"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "cypress/e2e/features/*.feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true
  }

Note: I'm using VS Code and if I revert back to "cypress\support\step_definitions" file directory it will work. This is the version of my cucumber  "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^21.0.3",
I also tried to use this syntax: cypress/e2e/step_definitions/**/*.{js,ts} but its not working
Screenshot:





This question is similar to: cypress can't find step definitions. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
